# Performing matched risk set sampling (incidence density sampling) without replacement matching on two variables

Tags: r, lubridate, sample, exposure

I have a dataframe like the example below:

```
### Packages needed for reproducible example
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

### Create data frame:
Person_IDs <- seq(1,1000000,1)
Example_DF <- as.data.frame(Person_IDs)

### Sex and age for matching:
set.seed(2021)
Example_DF$Sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1000000, replace = T)
set.seed(2021)
Example_DF$Age <- sample(c(1:100), size = 1000000, replace = T)

### Study start and end date (just for clarity):
Example_DF$Start_Date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
Example_DF$End_Date <- as.Date("2021-05-01")

### Study outcome (85% not experiencing the outcome, 15% experiencing the outcome):
set.seed(2021)
Example_DF$Outcome <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 1000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.85, 0.15))

### Timestamp for outcome (either as exposed (Outcome = 1) or censored (Outcome = 0):
Example_DF$Timestamp_Outcome <- as.Date("1900-01-01") 
set.seed(2021)
Example_DF$Timestamp_Outcome[Example_DF$Outcome == 1] <- Example_DF$Start_Date[Example_DF$Outcome == 1] + days(sample (c(45:295), size=length(unique(Example_DF$Person_IDs[Example_DF$Outcome == 1])), replace =T)) 
set.seed(2021)
Example_DF$Timestamp_Outcome[Example_DF$Outcome == 0] <- Example_DF$Start_Date[Example_DF$Outcome == 0] + days(sample (c(275:340), size=length(unique(Example_DF$Person_IDs[Example_DF$Outcome == 0])), replace =T)) 

### Arrange data by timestamp outcome:
Example_DF <- Example_DF %>% arrange(Timestamp_Outcome)

### Show first rows of data frame:
head(Example_DF)
```

As you can see, there are:

1. 1000000 unique individuals (Person_IDs) with a common start date of 2020-01-01 (i.e. the column Start_Date is set to 2020-01-01" for all individuals) and a common end date (End_Date) of "2021-05-01".
2. Information on sex and age is available, which will be used to "match" IDs where Outcome == 1 with controls.
3. All individuals have a date of an outcome (either with Outcome == 0 or Outcome == 1).

**What I want to perform now is something referred to as risk set sampling (or incidence density sampling). The dataframe is arranged by timestamp of outcome and now:

1. Each time the "algorithm" encounters a row where the Outcome == 1,  a random selection of three (3) Person_IDs who have the same sex, the same age AND a later timestamp (i.e. Timestamp_Outcome is at least one day later, irrespective of if Outcome == 0 or Outcome == 1) should be performed.
2. These 4 individuals (the 1 exposed individual and the 3 unexposed individuals) should then be removed from the dataframe (i.e. replace = FALSE) and can thus NOT be selected again (referred to as sampling without replacement).**

To make it more clear if needed, consider the following example:

```
head(Example_DF)
```

As you can see, Person_ID 1030, 1269, 3180, 4245 etc all experience the outcome at 2020-02-15. Taking Person_ID 1030 as an example, this is a 86 year old female. She should thus be matched against three 86 year old females NOT exposed at 2020-02-15 (they can become exposed 2020-02-16, 2020-02-20 or anytime onwards). If this is not possible, as many matched individuals as possible should be selected (ranging from 0 to 3 matched individuals).

Any idea of how this can be performed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution using `data.table` and recursion:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

dt <- data.table(Person_IDs = 1:1e6, Start_Date = as.Date("2020-01-01"), Exposure_Date = as.Date("2020-01-01") + days(sample(c(45:365), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE)), End_Date = as.Date("2021-05-01"), Sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE), Age = sample(c(1:100), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE))

matched_risk_sample_rec <- function(id, Exposure_Date, size = 5L, out_vec, idx = 1L) {
  # perform the matched risk sampling
  
  # get the index of the next unexposed person
  idxUnexposed <- sum(Exposure_Date == Exposure_Date[1]) + 1L
  
  if (length(id) - idxUnexposed + 1L < size) {
    # not enough for another sample set
    return(out_vec)
  }
  
  # get a sample set
  sample.id <- c(1L, sample(idxUnexposed:length(id), size = size, replace = FALSE))
  out_vec[idx:(idx + size)] <- id[sample.id]
  # remove the samples and recurse
  return(matched_risk_sample_rec(id[-sample.id], Exposure_Date[-sample.id], size, out_vec, idx + size + 1L))
}

# order the dataset by Sex, Age, and Exposure_Date, and mark as sorted
setkey(dt, Sex, Age, Exposure_Date)

# add a column for the sample set ordering
# every 6 values of "set_ids" is a sample set of IDs, with the first value being the exposed person id
dt[, set_ids := matched_risk_sample_rec(Person_IDs, Exposure_Date, 5L, rep(NA, .N)), by = .(Sex, Age)]
# rearrange the data.table by the "set_ids" column
# override "set_ids" with a unique ID for each set
dtSamples <- dt[dt[!is.na(set_ids), "set_ids"], on = .(Person_IDs == set_ids)][, set_ids := rep(1:(.N/6L), each = 6L)]
```

`dtSamples` now has 166588 sample sets of 6 persons each, with the first in each set being the exposed person.

Comment: This is great and helped me realize that some more conditions has to be set for the algorithm. Please see updated question (where a new column called Outcome (0/1 variable) has to be specified.